# Open IE in kiosk mode BUT not maximized

Tags: windows, internet-explorer

Can we open IE in a kiosk mode - but not in a maximized view? We are trying to open an IE instance from a C#.NET app. This instance opens in a kiosk mode but disables the user to select 'OK' on the print preview pop up (as IE is maximized covering the whole screen). We want some way to open ONLY a specific page in IE (thus in kiosk mode) but not covering the full screen so that the user can choose the print options. 
Alternatively is there a way to completely disable the print options and print silently using the default options?
Any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for the [WebBrowser control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w290k23d.aspx), which allows you to embed IE inside your program.

Comment: Alternatively is there a way to completely disable the print options and print silently using the default options?

Comment: @deveffort: Try `webBrowser.Document.ExecCommand("Print", false, null)`.  However, I don't think it'll work.

Comment: For a System.Windows.Forms WebBrowser, it is: webbrowser.Print()

For a WPF WebBrowser, something like this:

mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 doc = webbrowser.Document as mshtml.ITHMLDocument2;  doc.execCommnad("Print", false, null);

Comment: Which one?  If you call .Print() on a System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser, it will print the document currently displayed in the browser using the current printer and page settings.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look into Microsoft HTML Applications:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536496%28VS.85%29.aspx

They are going to give a little more control over how the chrome of the application is displayed, and runs within the context of the currently logged in user.

Comment: Is there any IE setting to completely ignore the print options and print silently?

Comment: Without putting fingers to keys, yes, I believe so.  You can drop vbscript into an hta with system privileges:

Comment: Sorry, skipped some links for you:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692768.aspx and http://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_printing_print.php should get you started.

Comment: Is there any firefox settings (via the about:config) or something that can prevent the print dialog? I tried the print.always_print_silent but this does not seem to work. All I want is that users start print if they want to without them seeing another pop up box (either on FF or IE)